# Unable to send push notification to android phone from parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I am new to android development and parse.com. I am trying to send a push notification from the web console (parse.com) to android emulator. Though I get a success on the web console but I do not receive any notification on the device. Moreover, I get this error :

```
`02-04 17:54:52.100    2501-2520/com.parse.starter E/com.parse.ManifestInfo﹕Cannot use GCM for push because the app manifest is missing some required declarations. Please make sure that these permissions are declared as children of the root     <manifest> element:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"     android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    Also, please make sure that these services and broadcast receivers are     declared as children of the <application> element:
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"     android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
<category android:name="com.parse.starter" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Here's my Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.parse.starter"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!--
  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
  to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
-->
<permission
    android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />

<!--
 To retrieve OAuth 2.0 tokens or invalidate tokens to disconnect a user. This disconnect
 option is required to comply with the Google+ Sign-In developer policies
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" /> <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />

<application
    android:name=".ParseApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <!-- IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name. -->
            <category android:name="com.pase.starter" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
   </application>

 </manifest>
```

And in my application class, I have defined this:

```
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
        } else {
            Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I am following the push-notification guide provided by parse.com

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24949806/3310181 ..plse see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.parse.starter"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!--
 To retrieve OAuth 2.0 tokens or invalidate tokens to disconnect a user. This disconnect
 option is required to comply with the Google+ Sign-In developer policies
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" /> <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />

<application
    android:name=".ParseApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <!-- IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name. -->
            <category android:name="com.pase.starter" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!--
  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
  to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
-->
<permission
    android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />

   </application>

 </manifest>
```

I'm not in Android Studio right now so I can't test it, but I think it should work !